# Parse human-readable sizes (k, M, G, T) into bytes in C

Tags: c, parsing, scanf, atoi

I'm looking for a quick way to parse human-readable byte sizes (examples: 100, 1k, 2M, 4G) into a byte values.  The input is a `char *` and the output must be a `size_t` (e.g. unsigned, likely 64-bit or 32-bit integer, depending on architecture).  The code should detect invalid input and return an value indicating that it was invalid input.

Examples:

```
Input  => size_t result
-----------------------
"100"  => 100
"10k"  => 10240
"2M"   => 2097152
"4G"   => 4294967296 on 64-bit machine, error (overflow) on 32-bit machine
"ten"  => error
```

Here is an example fragment of code to be expanded to handle the unit prefixes:

```
int parse_human_readable_byte_size(char *input, size_t *result) {
    /* TODO: needs to support k, M, G, etc... */
    return sscanf("%zu", result) == 1;
}
```

Here are some additional requirements:

- must be done in C (no C++)
- use only standard libraries (or at least commonly available) libraries (e.g. `sscanf`, `atoi`)

The code is expected to run only a few times per program execution, so smaller readable code is favored over longer higher-performance code.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a sensible solution but maybe you can try `size_t array_t[2]` and split the big number into two halves

Comment: Hi SuvP, didn't mean to imply that my code snippet above was a working solution--only to provide an example of what the code needs to do.  The actual solution can come in any (similar) form.

Comment: I meant what I am suggesting doesn't comes across a sensible solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a potential implementation. Code to detect all errors is included; fill in your own handling in place of the `goto`s if you like.

```
char *endp = s;
int sh;
errno = 0;
uintmax_t x = strtoumax(s, &endp, 10);
if (errno || endp == s) goto error;
switch(*endp) {
case 'k': sh=10; break;
case 'M': sh=20; break;
case 'G': sh=30; break;
case 0: sh=0; break;
default: goto error;
}
if (x > SIZE_MAX>>sh) goto error;
x <<= sh;
```

Comment: Very nice.  I think it needs one small addition after the switch `if (sh && endp[1]) goto error;` to handle input with extra characters at end.

Answer (score 1):

Based on accepted answer, I updated the snipped.
It support float input (like `1.5k`), support hexadecimal input (like `0x55k`), drop `gotos` and use a string as list of units to avoid the switch and makes the update easy.

```c
static char *human_readable_suffix = "kMGT";

size_t *parse_human_readable(char *input, size_t *target) {
    char *endp = input;
    char *match = NULL;
    size_t shift = 0;
    errno = 0;

    long double value = strtold(input, &endp);
    if(errno || endp == input || value < 0)
        return NULL;

    if(!(match = strchr(human_readable_suffix, *endp)))
        return NULL;

    if(*match)
        shift = (match - human_readable_suffix + 1) * 10;

    *target = value * (1LU << shift);

    return target;
}
```

Here are the tests result:

```
1337   =>           1337 [ok, expected: 1337]
857.54 =>            857 [ok, expected: 857]
128k   =>         131072 [ok, expected: 131072]
1.5k   =>           1536 [ok, expected: 1536]
8M     =>        8388608 [ok, expected: 8388608]
0x55   =>             85 [ok, expected: 85]
0x55k  =>          87040 [ok, expected: 87040]
1T     =>  1099511627776 [ok, expected: 1099511627776]
32.    =>             32 [ok, expected: 32]
-87    => error (expected)
abcd   => error (expected)
32x    => error (expected)
```

Full code can be found at: https://gist.github.com/maxux/786a9b8bf55fb0696f7e31b8fa3f6b9d

Answer (score 0):

I'll try with a sub-function that analyzes the input char by char.

Further an obvious error check, I'll make it translate symbols in numeric constant, multiplied for the base corresponding to the constant.